With my resident permit of Italy do I need a visa to travel to Montenegro?
With my resident permit of Italy do I need a visa to travel to Montenegro?

It’s not always the case, in some cases visa requirements change based whether you have schengen visa. The examples are Turkey and Saudi Arabia, they offer e-visa or visa on arrival for anyone who has residence permit/valid visa from US/UK/EU.

Yes, a Schengen residence permit allows one visa-free entry to Montenegro. But the OP will also need a passport. Does the OP have one?

It depends.
A residence permit from a Schengen country allows you to enter and stay in Montenegro for 30 days.
Unless your citizenship is of one of the countries for which Montenegro allows 90 days visa free stay, you will need to apply for a visa if your plan is to stay longer than 30 days.
